# In principle, can energy "tunnel" directly out of a black hole? If not, why not?

Tags: black-holes, quantum-tunneling, black-hole-firewall

Energy seems to quantum tunnel through normally impenetrable barriers, so I wonder why not the back side of an event horizon?

Comment: please see my answer to a duplicate here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/482651/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, there is a phenomenon of quantum tunnelling and black holes. It's related to Hawking Radiation! Hawking Radiation can in fact be modelled as a qauntum tunnelling effect. Here are two papers discussing the quantum tunnelling from black holes: [quantum tunnelling from three dimensional black holes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6380)
and quantum tunnelling in [black holes](http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6008). Another paper discussing quantum tunnelling can be found [here](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ahep/2015/898916/). Here is the paper where [Hawking Radiation is modelled as a quantum tunnelling effect](http://www.cscanada.net/index.php/ans/article/view/j.ans.1715787020120502.1817).

Comment: Oh wow, exactly what I was looking for thanks!  Would this basically solve the firewall problem?  a.k.a. just tunnel information out?

Comment: If by the firewall problem you refer to the motivating paradox in [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(physics)) wikipedia page, then the answer is not really, for the phenomenon was known before the formulation of the paradox. Read up on these two papers: [1](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9306083) and [2](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9305007), to understand the paradox, and [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1207.3123) paper for a possible yet controversial solution.